# my jquery ajax request is not accessing the the database?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, html

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    /* fetch elements and stop form event */
    $("form.follow-form").submit(function (e) {
        /* stop event */
        e.preventDefault();
        /* "on request" */
        $(this).find('i').addClass('active');
        /* send ajax request */
        $.post('recycle.php', {
            followID: $(this).find('input').val()
        }, function () {
            /* find and hide button, create element */
            $(e.currentTarget)
              .find('button').hide()
              .after('<span class="following"><span></span>Following!</span>');
        });
    });
});
```

the html:

```
<form class="follow-form" method="post" action="recycle.php">
    <input name="id" value="$id" type="hidden">
        <input name="$tweet" value="$tweet" type="hidden">
    <button type="submit" value="Actions" class="btn follow" title="123456">
        <i></i><span>recyle</span>
    </button>
</form>
```

reycle.php:

```
<?php session_start();
include_once ('includes/connect.php');

$id = $_POST['id'];
$tweet =$_POST['tweet'];


  $registerlistener = mysql_query("INSERT INTO notes (user_id, user_note,recyle_id,dt) VALUES('".$_SESSION['user_id']."','".$tweet."','".$id."',NOW()");



?>
```

the problem is that it's not accessing the recycle.php file, which inserts the information from the html form into the database! but it's doing the whole jquery animation!! i dont see whats the problem!!!

Comment: what is the "whole jquery animation"?

Comment: basically when i click the reycle button it changes into text saying "recycled"

Comment: Should this `value="$id"` not be `value="<?php echo $id ?>"`, and same with `$tweet`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var_dump()` the `$_POST` variable in your php script and check the response with firebug (Firefox extension). This way you can see what gets through.

But i think there is a problem with your data collecting.
This might work:

```
$.post('recycle.php', {
   id: $(this).find('input[name=id]').attr('value'),
   tweet: $(this).find('input[name~=tweet]').attr('value')
   },
   function(response){
   //on success code
   });
```

You can confirm this either with firebug logging (`console.log`) or with `var_dump` results.

Answer (score 0):

Use firebug console or something similar and see if there are any `404`or other errors. If you don't see any 404 errors, check if your `php` script.

Comment: ive added the php scirpt, its not adding nothing to the database

Comment: Check the logic and what going on in the PHP script. A debugging effort can help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax certainly looks fine, try adding the variables for the callback into the signature

Comment: sorry i dnt get what u mean, im a bit of a newbie here